# How to safely discharge UPS using workstation (prevent filesystem damage)

Tags: linux, kernel, storage, readonly, ups

I'm using quite big UPS comparing to hardware attached to it in order to achieve longer uptime on UPS (up to 1h). However as maintenance practice it's advised to discharge it at least every 3 months. Unfortunately the only machine that is capable of discharging this UPS in any reasonable time is 1kW workstation under 100% load. But it got tons of drives so I'm a bit worried about data consistency.

Is there any way in linux to switch drives (during OS uptime) to read only mode after `sync` so that there won't be any data corruption after outage?

I'm looking in the end for something like this:

```
#Blender headless running on all GPUs and all cores wasting 100% power

sync
<command to force remount all drives in read only mode>

#here after around 30 min comes power outage
```

I'm using btrfs as filesystem so any uncontrolled outage is quite dangerous. I tried those low-level kernel requests with `sysrq` key but one for readonly remount doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Can you discharge it using something other than an important computer, say, a space heater or an air conditioner?

Comment: hmm I don't happen to have any unfortunately :( This PC is huge leap, second most powerful devices are probably 80W Eizo CX monitors but it's around 10 times lower power consumption. What is some cheap device that uses lots of power I could get just for this purpose?

Comment: Space heaters are cheap. I got a 1500-watt one for $30 at the local hardware store.

Comment: Also, many UPSs have a USB or D-sub connector that you can connect to your computer and with [appropriate software](http://networkupstools.org/) shut down the computer when the battery is about to run out.